# How to avoid race conditions on celery tasks?

Tags: python, django, database, celery, race-condition

Considering the following task:

```
@app.task(ignore_result=True)
def withdraw(user, requested_amount):
    if user.balance >= requested_amount:
        send_money(requested_amount)
        user.balance -= requested_amount
        user.save()
```

If this task gets executed twice, at the same time, it would result in an user with a negative balance... how can I solve it? It is just an example of race, but there are lots of situations like this in my code..

Comment: why not use atomic transactions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [this](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/task-cookbook.html?highlight=lock#ensuring-a-task-is-only-executed-one-at-a-time) Celery cookbook recipe to implement a Lock which will make sure that only one task is run at a time, and then perhaps implement [retry](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html?highlight=retry#retrying) logic to then try the second task again later. Something like this;

```
def import_feed(self, feed_url):
    # The cache key consists of the task name and the MD5 digest
    # of the feed URL.
    feed_url_hexdigest = md5(feed_url).hexdigest()
    lock_id = '{0}-lock-{1}'.format(self.name, feed_url_hexdigest)
    logger.debug('Importing feed: %s', feed_url)
    with memcache_lock(lock_id, self.app.oid) as acquired:
        if acquired:
            return Feed.objects.import_feed(feed_url).url
    self.retry(countdown = 2)
```

Comment: while this might be a good solution for small apps, it would not scale well.. I was looking for a method to avoid race based on db, regardless of how many tasks are accessing it..

Comment: Then do it with the database: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_for_update

Comment: I saw an article in medium talking about it https://medium.com/@hakibenita/how-to-manage-concurrency-in-django-models-b240fed4ee2 and another question here recommending the select_for_update method.. now that you recommended  it as well, I see no other way to go.. Thanks